# How to fix ERR_CERT_REVOKED issue in iPhone for GoDaddy issued certificate?

Tags: iphone, ssl

I am getting ERR_CERT_REVOKED in iPhone while accessing our website which uses a GoDaddy SSL certificate. It works fine on Laptop on all browsers but gives this error on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godaddy is facing an AutoSSL technical issue where they are not able to renew the SSL certificate. Mine has been down for 2 days now and has contacted their support multiple times. No permanent fix as of now.

You can do these steps which can put you in the queue for AutoSSL renewal. They haven't mentioned a timeframe for the resolution of this issue, unfortunately.

Steps:

1. Go to Cpanel of Hosting
2. Select **SSL/TLS**
3. Select **Generate, view, upload, or delete SSL certificates**.
4. Delete all self-signed certificates
5. Go to Cpanel and select **SSL/TLS Status**
6. Select all domains you want to renew and click **Run AutoSSL**

This will put your domain in the queue for renewal.

> God knows when these guys will resolve the issue and renew it though.